# Migrating to Pgrouting pgr_dijkstra?

Tags: pgrouting

I have a system that uses [shortest_path](http://pgrouting.org/docs/1.x/dijkstra.html) function pgrouting 1.x. At the moment, I want to migrate to pgrouting 2. And I assume the equivalent function to shortest_path is [pgr_dijkstra](http://docs.pgrouting.org/dev/src/dijkstra/doc/index.html). (Correct?)

When running this, (Hibernate Query Language)

```
SELECT SUM(t2.length) as totalLength FROM (
    SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra(
        'SELECT gid AS id, source::int4, target::int4, 
                cost::double precision AS cost, 
                reverse_cost::double precision as reverse_cost 
            FROM openstreetmap',5374,5364, false, true
    )) AS t1, openstreetmap AS t2 WHERE t1.edge_id = t2.gid
```

I get error
ERROR: column t1.edge_id does not exist

What is the edge_id in the output of pgr_dijkstra ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [new Dijkstra](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/dijkstra/doc/index.html#pgr-dijkstra) function returns a different result set type named [pgr_costResult (seq, id1, id2, cost)](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/common/doc/types/cost_result.html#type-cost-result)

Look at this example from the documentation to see how you can rename the column names using aliases:

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost
        FROM pgr_dijkstra(
                'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM edge_table',
                7, 12, true, true
        );

 seq | node | edge | cost
-----+------+------+------
   0 |    7 |    8 |    1
   1 |    8 |    9 |    1
   2 |    9 |   15 |    1
   3 |   12 |   -1 |    0
(4 rows)
```

So you either change the alias to match with `edge_id` or you join with `id2`.